# How to automatically select HDMI audio after sleep?

Tags: sound, xubuntu, 20.04, pulseaudio, hdmi

My system has 2 audio devices.

1. TU116 HDMI through the monitor
2. "Built-in audio analog stereo" which is for a headphone jack

Both work fine. But after the system puts the monitor to sleep, it switches everything to #2. So I have to go the pulse audio panel plugin and select the HDMI again every time the the monitor wakes up.

I tried commenting out the line:
#load-module module-switch-on-port-available
in /etc/pulse/default.pa, but it had no effect.

Is there anyway to prevent the switching from HDMI to the other audio device, or to automatically re-select the HDMI after sleep?

Under windows, if I had audio playing it on the monitor, the audio would shut off with the monitor, but resume when the monitor woke up. This is the desired behavior, and shows it is possible.

**UPDATE**
I don't want to disable the analog device, because sometimes I use that for headphones.
From PulseAudio 13.0 release note: "Automatically switch away from unavailable card profiles... A common case is a HDMI profile that becomes unavailable when a monitor is detached. Playback should now automatically move to somewhere else when a HDMI monitor is detached."

Is seems the "module-switch-on-port-available" is supposed to switch back to the HDMI when it becomes available, but it doesn't.

I tried just about every combination of modules and setting the default sink to HDMI, bit no luck.

Comment: I don't mind the HDMI audio cutting off. It's the pulse audio switching the default audio to the analog audio. There must be a way to prevent this.